# T-SQL: efficiently DELETE records in right table that are not in left table when using RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is a SELECT statement showing records that are representative in the right table, but not the left table, when the FK in the right table exists, but there is no PK in the left table.  I'd like to DELETE records from the right table that have dangling pointers (basically the [FACT] records from this result set).  **How can I do the delete efficiently using the result set I have below?**  I was going to do a NOT IN clause, but I'm thinking it would take way to long to join the parent and the child/nested query.  That was the whole reason I used a right join ***instead of using NOT IN*** in the first place, because I have billions of records.

```
SELECT
    [FACT].[FK]
FROM
    [DIMENSION]
    RIGHT JOIN [FACT] ON [FACT].[FK] = [DIMENSION].[PK]
WHERE
    [FACT].[TYPE] LIKE 'LAB%' AND [DIMENSION].[PK] IS NULL
```

Comment: NOT IN / NOT EXISTS would be faster provided that PK and FK are non-nullable fields see [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Comment: Why RIGHT JOIN? So much more logical to think about this as the important tables listed first, and those that might not have a row listed second. IMHO, anyway. As for performance, instead of wondering what might be slower or faster and making assumptions about behavior, why not TEST IT? http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: The short answer is because I already spend too much time messing around copying and restoring, when I have the experts on here, like yourself.  My normal job is not cleaning up data.  I would run short of disk space if I made a copy of this table, and it takes 2 hours to load it again using our ETL tools from the source system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM [FACT]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [DIMENSION]
                  WHERE [FACT].[FK] = [DIMENSION].[PK]
                   AND  [FACT].[TYPE] LIKE 'LAB%')
```

Since these are FACT and DIM tables I think you will be deleting Large amount of data, otherwise you wouldn't care much about the performance. Another thing you can consider when delete large amount of data is, Deleting it in Smaller chunks. By doing something as below

```
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;


WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
  BEGIN
   -- Delete some small number of rows at a time
    DELETE TOP (10000) FROM [FACT]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [DIMENSION]
                      WHERE [FACT].[FK] = [DIMENSION].[PK]
                       AND  [FACT].[TYPE] LIKE 'LAB%')

  SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM [FACT] 
WHERE [FACT].[TYPE] LIKE 'LAB%' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DIMENSION] WHERE [FACT].[FK] = [DIMENSION].[PK]) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly. Your above query already pulls all the rows you want to delete from the `right` table.

```
DELETE FACT
FROM
    [DIMENSION]
    RIGHT JOIN [FACT] ON [FACT].[FK] = [DIMENSION].[PK]
WHERE
    [FACT].[TYPE] LIKE 'LAB%' AND [DIMENSION].[PK] IS NULL
```

Comment: I guess I missed something, downvoted with no explanation why.

Comment: seems they've undone it, but in any case, just accept that down-votes are an unavoidable part of posting answers for peer review. Whining about it isn't going to make them more likely to say anything.